# How to use one target in multiple targets' 'depends' property in ANT build?

Tags: ant

I am using ANT build for deployment process. For that, I followed the below points,

> 1. Created five targets in ANT named 'initiate.deploy' (to initiate
>      deployment), 'svn.checkout' (checkout source from SVN into
>      workspace) , 'generate.ear' (EAR generation) and 'deploy.ear'
>      (deploy EAR into Server), 'clean.workspace' (Cleaning workspace
>      dirtory).
> 2. The target 'initiate.deploy' is my default target.
> 3. I need to clean the workspace directory before 'svn.checkout' target
>      and after 'deploy.ear' target.
> 4. I put 'clean.workspace' target in 'depends' property of
>      'svn.checkout' target and in 'initiate.deploy' target.

My Code:

```
    <target name="initiate.deploy" description="Initiate deployment" depends="svn.checkout, generate.ear, deploy.ear, clean.workspace">
        ..........................
    </target>

    <target name="svn.checkout" description="SVN checkout" depends ="clean.workspace">
        ..........................
    </target>
```

But the target 'clean.workspace' is executed only once before 'svn.checkout' but not after 'deploy.ear' target.

Build sequence is created as follows.

> Build sequence for target(s) 'initiate.deploy' is [clean.workspace,
>   svn.checkout, check.workSpace, update.property.file, generate.ear,
>   deploy.ear, initiate.deploy]

How to use one target in multiple targets' 'depends' property in ANT build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html):

> In a chain of dependencies stretching back from a given target such as
>   D above, each target gets executed only once, even when more than one
>   target depends on it.

My understanding is that this is designed to avoid cycles in the dependencies graph.

Due to this, you need to modify your targets, for example by removing `clean.workspace` from the dependencies of `initiate.deploy` and invoking it explicitely via the `antcall` task:

```
<target name="initiate.deploy" description="Initiate deployment" depends="svn.checkout, generate.ear, deploy.ear">
    ..........................
    <antcall target="clean.workspace" />
</target>

<target name="svn.checkout" description="SVN checkout" depends ="clean.workspace">
    ..........................
</target>
```

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, the `antcall` task will start the invoked target in a new Ant project, which can create an undesirable overhead. To avoid this behavior, it is possible to wrap the target as a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) and invoke it as a task in any other target. You may then change the invoked target such that it calls the new `macrodef`, in order to keep it available as a dependency of other tasks:

```
<target name="initiate.deploy" description="Initiate deployment" depends="svn.checkout, generate.ear, deploy.ear">
    ..........................
    <clean.workspace.macro />
</target>

<target name="svn.checkout" description="SVN checkout" depends ="clean.workspace">
    ..........................
</target>

<target name="clean.workspace">
    <clean.workspace.macro />
</target>

<macrodef name="clean.workspace.macro">
   <sequential>
        <!-- do the workspace cleanup -->
        ..........................
   </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Its very clear. But when we use antcall, it starts a new instance of Ant build. Is it right?

Comment: @AJK yes, you are right, the invoked target will be started in a new Ant project. I updated the answer to reflect this and propose an alternative

Comment: Thank you. As I am new to Ant, I have learnt the new and important one from this.

Comment: How to use **'if'** property in **macrodef** as I need to execute one task only if a property is set.